# Static IP address set in /etc/network/interface not getting updated after rmmod and insmod

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ethernet, network-interface

I have configured static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` file as below

```
# The loopback interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

# Wired or wireless interfaces
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    hwaddress ether 01:06:92:85:00:12
```

But, when i try to do `rmmod` of the driver e1000 and then
`insmod` again. the eth0 network interface would be loaded but, the ip address is not assigned until i explicitly do `ifconfig eth0` or `ifup eth0`.

I have tried adding a script in /etc/network/if-up.d/loadeth.sh
which has

```
#!/bin/sh

 if [ "$IFACE" = eth0 ]; then
        echo "eth0 up" >> /var/log/oak_pci.log
 fi
```

but, no luck the IP address is getting assigned.

My aim is that whenever i `insmod` the ethernet device driver i want to get the network interface(`eth0`) assigned with static IP address i have assigned in the `interfaces` file

Could anybody let me know what am i missing here

Comment: Does adding the line `allow-hotplug eth0` help?

Comment: I tried allow-hotplug eth0 but, It didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through man page of udev i understood how to create udev rules and with a dummy test specified in this link https://www.tecmint.com/udev-for-device-detection-management-in-linux/ i was able to invoke the udev rules when `insmod`-ing and `rmmod`-ing a driver.

So, Here's what i did to automatically set the ip address for the ethernet network interface once driver is loaded or `insmod`ed

I create a udev rules file named `80-net_auto_up.rules` in the ethernet pcie driver recipe (it is an out of tree kernel module. Hence, custom recipe)

i added `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/sbin/ifup eth0"`

and edited ethernet pcie driver recipe .bb file and added below lines

```
...

SRC_URI = "all source files of ethernet pcie driver
           file://80-net_auto_up.rules \
          "

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d/*"

do_install_append() {

    ...
    
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/80-net_auto_up.rules ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d/
}
```

and now it works. when i reset the ethernet device manually.
The device is getting detected and Static IP address configured in the `/etc/network/interfaces` is set

Answer (score 1):

> what am i missing here

The files in `/etc/network/` are parsed when when `ifup` or `ifdown` commands are executed. (I think also when `ifplugd` picks them up).

`insmod` loads a module into the running kernel.

You are missing the knowledge, that there is just no connection between `insmod`-ing a kernel driver and reading any files from `/etc/network` directory.

> My aim is that whenever i insmod the ethernet device driver i want to get the network interface(eth0) assigned with static IP address i have assigned in the interfaces file

You may setup `udev` rule to run a custom script upon `insmod`-ing a kernel driver or when interface comes up.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to setup udev rules. i tried adding rules like "SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNELS=="0000:00:03.0", NAME=="eth0"
and placed it in the /etc/udev/rules.d and /lib/udev/rules.d/ but, nothing worked

Comment: I followed the procedure mentioned in this link https://packetpushers.net/udev/

Comment: First, listen on udef events with I think `udevadm monitor`. Then insmod/rmmod your module and check for events. Then write a rule that will match with some debugging output to `logger`. Then refresh udev rules with some command. Watch journal to see if the rule is really executing. I'm am really bad at udev, it's always pain for me - once it works, it works.